# Write to console synchronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

I need to debug a time-critical crash I have in my App and since NSLog does not immediately write to the console I am wondering if there is a way to synchronously write to the console from my code.

So for example is `printf` a better choice here or would I have to deal with the same problems.

Comment: `printf` is also buffered, so at the very least you should `fflush(stdout)` right after the call of `printf`.

Comment: Well NSLog prints out its messages to stderr, which is not buffered (you could achieve the same with fprintf(stderr,...)). So I think for console output this is the best you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint before the crashing line(s), though I think Xcode by default already hangs the proccess so that you can still access the debugger console ... If it doesn't, you may want to add some additional diagnostics by going to Product -> Edit Scheme .. (in the upper menu), such as Guard Edges, Zombie Objects, etc.

In addition, you can call `NSLog` from the main thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"String .." waitUntilDone:YES];

- (void)log:(NSString *)message {
    NSLog(message);
}
```